# Close a buffer without close the window

Tags: neovim

### To solve this issue, I just find a plugin: https://github.com/ojroques/nvim-bufdel

Hi there,

I am a beginner of NVIM, I have a question about the two plugins in the title.

For example,

I have two tabs right now:

[image: FIG.1]

If I close one tab, it will be like this:

[image: fig.2]

But I want the nvim looks like the fig.3 after I close a tab:

[image: fig.3]

Can you help me?

The command I used to close the tab is: `bd!`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is confusing. Could you reformulate it? Could you then explain the part for which you have an answer and the part that is still open?

Comment: Hi, the question actually is, in vim, when we close a buffer, the window of that buffer will also close. That's why after I close a buffer, the file bowser(fig.2) will be full screen. But I want after I close a buffer, the vim will look like fig.3. Is this clear?

Comment: Your question says "close a tab," but you use the `:bdelete` (buffer delete) command. What about `:tabclose`? Or are you using a "tabline" plugin that shows buffers in the tabline (instead of tabs)?

Comment: Hi, that's actually my fault. I am a beginner of nvim, I should call `buffer` instead of `tab`. Sorry for that.

Comment: Whether it is buffer / tab / window , clearly there is a BUG in neovim ! **In Image 1** , there is a file Explorer on the left , on the right , there are two files , basic.lua & plugins.lua , which is fine. **In Image 2** , when basic.lua was closed , we should have file Explorer & plugins.lua but what we get is "title" of plugins.lua with "contents" of file Explorer which is a BUG , clearly in neovim ! In **Image 3** , we have file Explorer & plugins.lua which is correct.

Comment: Hi Perm. After discovering this, I find this actually is not a bug. This actually is a feature. Basically, in vim, every buffer is displayed on a window. Nvim will default close the window when the corresponding buffer is closed. That's the reason for Fig.2.